# Copy data with in sheets

Tags: excel, vba, copy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPzmu.png)There are 2 sheets, Sheet1 and Sheet2. 
Sheet1 contain 10 columns and 5 rows with data including blank.

The requirement is to copy the data from Sheet 1 and to put in another sheet Sheet 2, wherein only populate the cell which is not blank.

I get the run time error 1004 - Application or object defined error.

The code snippet is:-

```
 Set wsht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
 Set wsht2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
 finalrow = wsht1.Cells(wsht1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

 For i = 1 To finalrow
 If wsht1.Cells(i, 1).Value <> " " Then
    Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 2)).Copy 
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Select
        wsht2.Range(Cells(1, i)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

    End If
Next i
```

Can u help me in sorting this out?

Comment: You look to be switching to sheet 2, so the 2nd time the loop is run, Range(Cells.... will refer to and copy from sheet 2 not wsht1.   Where is the error?

Comment: the error occurs when i try to run the code!

Run time error - 1004
Application-defined or object defined error

Comment: @Prabhu what is this line `Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 2)).Copy` ? are you trying to copy a range of a single cell ?

Comment: @ShaiRado I want to copy that single cell (within that range) and paste it to the another sheet cell.

Comment: @Prabhu but in your code you are just copying the formats, do you want also to copy the values ?

Comment: @ShaiRado ?Yes i want to copy the values from the next column cell

Comment: @Prabhu let me know if the code in my answer below works for you

Comment: In what line does the error happen

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define a range like that:

```
wsht2.Range(Cells(1, i))
```

you might use:

```
wsht2.Cells(1, i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
```

BTW: with this code you won't find empty cells:

```
If wsht1.Cells(i, 1).Value <> " " Then
```

you should use:

```
If wsht1.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
```

(the difference is a missing space between the quotes)

if you want to copy the values only and to make it with a loop I'd do the following:

```
Sub copying()

    Set wsht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
     Set wsht2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
     finalrow = wsht1.Cells(wsht1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

 For i = 1 To finalrow
    If wsht1.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
        For j = 1 To 5
            wsht2.Cells(i, j).Value = wsht1.Cells(i, j).Value
        Next j
    End If
Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: I changed the code, but when i put a break, i can see the cellis copied but not pasted correctly to the destination

wsht2.Cells(i, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

Answer (score 1):

If you only have 5 cells with data in Sheet 1 and only want those 5 rows copying to Sheet 2 use the following, similar to Shai's answer above with an extra counter for the rows in Sheet 2.

```
Sub copying()

Set wsht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wsht2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
finalrow = wsht1.Cells(wsht1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
k = 1

For i = 1 To finalrow
    If wsht1.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
        For j = 1 To 5
            wsht2.Cells(k, j).Value = wsht1.Cells(i, j).Value
        Next j
        k = k + 1
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

EDIT

As per your comment if you want to dynamically change `j` replace `For j = 1 To 5` with

```
For j = 1 To wsht1.Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Comment: can i make the j value dynamic?

Comment: Do you mean if each row in Sheet 1 has different amounts of data per row?

Comment: I edited the answer to count the columns used in each row.

Comment: Great, working fine and thanks a lot for sharing your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will copy only values in Column A (non-empty cells) from Sheet 1 to Sheet2:

```
Dim j                           As Long

Set wsht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wsht2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
finalrow = wsht1.Cells(wsht1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

j = 1
For i = 1 To finalrow
    With wsht1
        ' if you compare to empty string, you need to remove the space inside the quotes
        If .Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" And .Cells(i, 1).Value <> " " Then
            .Cells(i, 1).Copy ' since you are copying a single cell, there's no need to use a Range
            wsht2.Range("A" & j).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Paste:=xlPasteFormats
            j = j + 1
        End If
    End With
Next i
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the code.
When I run the code, and indeed i get he values, but coming with blanks still :(

Comment: @Prabhu perhaps you also have spaces inside cells, try edited code

Comment: This code will always create blanks in `wsht2` because you are using `i` to say where to paste the data, you need a separate counter for sheet two like `j = 1, wsht2.Range("A" & j).PasteSpecial, j = j + 1`

Comment: @ShaiRado I had included the screenshot of the output as an image where in i still get the blank cell

Comment: Try my answer below.

Comment: @Prabhu forgot to add Paste counter for Non-blank cells, try now

Comment: @ShaiRado Still have blank :(

Comment: do you have values in column A with space inside ? 2 spaces ? what values are copied ?

Comment: @ShaiRado No there is no space, The copied values are with the blank entries as well

Comment: @Prabhu sre you sure you coped the last code here ? with J counter ? Please copy the code again, and I test it. I just tested again on my PC and it's working without copying blanks

Comment: @ShaiRado Hi, Yes it is working. 
Thanks a lot for your valuable timing

Comment: Thanks all for solving this issue.

Comment: This says it will only copy values but the code also copies the formats, be careful as it's a bit misleading.